# Connect app to custom db after deployment with boxfuse

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cloudcaptain

I need to use a custom db instead of one that boxfuse creates when deploying my application to aws. I created a aws rds database, and the app won't connect to it after deploying, instead it uses a database that boxfuse creates while deploying. I use flyway for migrations.
I tried to put the url, username and password into a configuration boxfuse.yml file, but nothing happens. 
I read the boxfuse documentation, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.
Is there a easy way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your own database and prevent Boxfuse from provisioning one for you, the easiest is to recreate your app with `-db.type=none` (see https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/springboot#databases)

Alternatively if you want to use both the Boxfuse-provisioned database and your own, you have to manually define a second DataSource bean with the correct connection parameters which you can then pass to Flyway or any other library requiring it.